# Google play publisher API v2 requires login when using .net libraries for serverside application publishing

Tags: c#, .net, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to use the `AndroidPublisherService` class offered by Google when referencing the [google play API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/).  However when I start using it on the very first action which is an Edits.Insert() I get a **Login Required** (401) response.

I have set an API key and that does not seem to change anything.  My code is as such.

```
var publisherService = new AndroidPublisherService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                                                               {
                ApiKey = "my api key",
                ApplicationName = "my application name"                                          
            });

var edits = publisherService.Edits;            
var editRequest = edits.Insert(null /* new AppEdit() */, packageName); 
appEdit = editRequest.Execute(); // Fails with login required at this point
```

I have logged into the developer console application and registered a service account.  From that service account I created an API Key.  I have also granted access to this service for the project I am interested in.

I have tried to follow the Java examples for this however they all pass in a service account name which I don't seem to see on the .NET SDK version.